# Save and Close buttons disabled in Infopath form

Tags: 2010, infopath, word, document-converter

I am converting a large MS Word document manually into an Infopath form in Sharepoint 2010.  After adding about 100 rows of text, I see that the Save and Close buttons are disabled on the Edit menu/Commit group ribbon.  What is happening?  Why is it happening?  And how can I work around this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to make your buttons work again:

- Go to the tab named "DATA"
- Now click on "Submit Options"
- Select the option "allow users to submit this form".
- Select from the pull down menu "SharePoint List". Then you will see the grey
  "save button"

These steps worked for me :)